# Flask sqlachemy handling multiple filters

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am wondering how are multiple filters handled? for example we have

```
*table*
class ExampleTable(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(90))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

and JSON data we get is

```
{
  "title": "test",
  "date": "2020-12-27"
}
```

for performing filter queries what i've done is following

```
if title != '' and date != '':
    data = [ example_json for example_json in ExampleTable.query.filter(ExampleTable.title.contains(json['title']).filter(ExampleTable.date.contains(json['date']).all() ]
elif title != '':
    data = [ example_json for example_json in ExampleTable.query.filter(ExampleTable.title.contains(json['title']).all() ]
else:
    data = [ example_json for example_json in ExampleTable.query.all() ]

return data
```

This is just example but you can see how repetitive it gets and if we have 5 or 10 filters checking each one individually against each other would take hours for such simple task

**What is proper way to handle multiple filter queries in SQL?**

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` methods return `query` instances, so you can add filters repeatedly, like this:

```py
query = ExampleTable.query()
if title:
    query = query.filter(ExampleTable.title.contains(json['title'])
if date:
    query = query.filter(ExampleTable.title.contains(json['date'])
result = query.all()
```